# How to fetch id with get method in django?

Tags: django, forms, get, fetch

I have a model named WorkOut that stores all the data regarding workout sessions. LIke type of workout, reps, weights etc. There are 2 columns that I do not fill initially. I am trying to fill them with button clicks. Start time and end time.

The idea is at the beginning of the set user will click a button and it will fill up the "start time" column with current time. At the end of the set they will click the other button to fill up the "end time" column.

To achieve this I need to fetch the id for that specific object(row). If I have 10 sets of workout, I need to get the id for each specific row so when button is clicked only the column associated to that row is updated.

It should be simple but I am struggling. This is how my attempt looks like-

```html
WorkOut.objects.get('id')
```

I am running a for loop to display the entire model on the template.  I checked by displaying all the id on my template, they are there. But the above code doesn't fetch individual id. When I know the id, I can go like this-

```html
WorkOut.objects.get(id=18)
```

And sure enough it works. But I want to fetch the id based on the button that is clicked. I am thinking if I can do that then this piece of code-

```html
WorkOut.objects.get('id')
time=datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
WorkOut.objects.filter(id=id).update(start=time)
```

...should do the trick. I fetch id, get current time and update column with it. Any idea how can I complete the fetch part?

Thank you for any input.

All these codes are from views.py. I have created a simple form for the button on template.

Please advise.

I have to mention, previous threads didn't get me results, hence my post.

Thank You.

Edit: Here is my model.py-

```html
class WorkOut(models.Model):
    date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
    day=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
    start=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=move)
    weight=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    rep=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    pedal= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)  
    stretchtype =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    note=models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

EDIT TWO:

This is how my form looks like on django template-

```html
<td>
            <form action="get" >
            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="start" id="id_start">Start Time</button>
            </form>
</td>
```

This is the button in question. This is in a for loop with other model fields. But those are not giving any trouble.

"start" is the model field that should be populated with current time after the button click. So I picked id="id_start".

I reference that in views.py like this-

```html
time=datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
WorkOut.objects.filter(id="id_start").update(start=time)
```

And the error I get is this-

```html
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'id_start'.
```

This is where I am stuck now. Any input will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any other field in workout table that is unique

Comment: No. Nothing else. Only the id field, which is auto generated of course. I just added the model in the main post for all to see.

Comment: So you should keep the id somewhere in form or as attribute in html

Comment: I tried. Didn't work for some reason. I tried id={{i.id}}, id="id_start" since "start" is the name of the field, also tried id="random_name" and none of them worked. Not sure why. So I am thinking it is the way I am fetching the id in views is the problem. Hence my post.

Comment: Please add your template code and update views.

Comment: I updated my post with the form and the views.py. I am getting the error --- Field 'id' expected a number but got 'id_start'.

Answer (score 0):

When You send data for frontend send data with id.

After that when user click a button to update data you can get the right id and apply filter on it.

```
WorkOut.objects.filter(id=id_from_frontend).update(add_the_filed_you_want)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I added my form and views.py at the bottom of my post under "EDIT TWO:". I am getting error --- Field 'id' expected a number but got 'id_start'.

Comment: The problem you but “id_star”, it should be id_star without “” because in this way you pass it as string

Comment: Well that gives me the error id_form is not defined.

Comment: In your model Workout there is no relation with another model, you only use CharField, so what you want to get? If you want to get record by ID, use WorkOut.objects.get(id=pass_the_id_here)

Comment: I am looking for the variable that should be used in place of "pass_the_id_here". These are auto generated ids by django. At button click I want to get the id of the instance for which the button was clicked. I am trying to get which variable get me that id.